# What do you do when your senior processor has the new person train people that have been there for years?

Tags: training

What do you do when your senior processor has the new person train people that have been there for years?

Comment: It's very unclear what your goal is here. Do you think you should be the one training them? If so, have you talked to your "senior processor" about this? If not, why not?

Comment: Do you mean Predecessor ?

Comment: Knowledge and teaching ability is not about years of service. I'd rather be taught maths by the new math teacher, then the 20 year great job janitor.

Comment: Is there concern about the new person teaching old (existing) skills or the new person teaching new skills that you didn't know you needed or just its a new person? What is it about the new person teaching that bothers you?

Comment: What you do is try to understand what the boss thinks you can learn from the new guy, and learn it. Traditional does not automatically mean better. (Neither does new, but until you've looked at both carefully and fairly you can't rule it out )